# How to perform the addition of 2 (base 16) numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, binary

for example 0101011(base 16) + 0111011 (base 16) =?
another ex: 7FE + 3AB = ?

Answer (score 3):

For your first example, all you need is $0+1=1+0=1, 1+1=2, 0+0=0$ as there are no carries.  For the second, you can make an addition table base 16 [image: like below] and add just like in base 10.  Anything with a 1 in the left place is a carry.

Answer (score 0):

$0101011+0111011 = 101011+111011 = 212022$ in every number system of base $>2$ (where the digit $2$ is allowed). Similarly, $11^3=12321$ in every number system of base $>3$, etc.

If you intended these as in *binary* format, then:
$$\begin{align}   & 0101011 \\ +&0111011 \\ \hline \\ &1100110
\end{align}$$
As Ross wrote, start from behind, you find $1+1$ that is $10$ in binary, so write down the zero and carry the $+1$ as remainder and add to the next digit, just as in decimal...

$\mathtt{7FE+3AB =(800-2)+3AB=BAB-2=BA9 }\ $ in hexadecimal.